# Iptables DROPs packet but I can still browse site

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, fail2ban

I have setup fail2ban behind an ELB following [this post](https://centos.tips/fail2ban-behind-a-proxyload-balancer/), everything seems to work and I get this:

```
root@ip-10-164-24-152:/home/ubuntu# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-apache-proxy
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j fail2ban-apache-proxy
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A fail2ban-apache-proxy -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: 86.191.20.43" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-apache-proxy -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

However, the rule says `DROP`, but I'm still able to browse my site! Why is this? Am I missing another flag for the rule?

Comment: Do you see the banned address in the forward-for field of the access logs?

Comment: I am pretty sure the rule does not drop I.e. Is not hit. You can look at the extended iptables output and see the hit counter for the drop and jump rules.

Comment: BTW: it might be less Performance hungry if using AWS VPC ACLs in Front of ELB like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123308/how-to-configure-aws-elb-to-block-certain-ip-addresses-known-spammers I am sure fail2ban would be able to start AWS CLI to add those

Comment: Yes, I see them in the access log and I'm able to browse my site even though I have been banned on fail2ban! I don't use VPC, still on the AWS classic.